# How I can get the same result in Python what I get by using Sumif in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables, first is input table which is shown below. I want to get the second table from the first table. Paid column in second table has come through SUMIF. Add column is difference between Grand Total and Paid amount. We have Total which is some of Grand Total. I want to get the second table by using Python. How I can do this?

1st Table-

| BAS | NA | NA |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Insurance | Amount |
| 10AB | AB | 20.00 |
| 10AC | AC | 15.00 |
| 10AC | AC1 | 12.00 |

2nd Table-

| Insurance | Paid | Add | NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10AB | 20.00 | 27 | NA |
| 10AC | 27.00 | 20.00 | Total |
| Grand Total | 47.00 | 27.00 | 74.00 |

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.groupby('Insurance')`?

This looks like Multindex to me. You can try by using Multiindex dataframe of Python.